# CKeditor inside Iframe problem

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

When we place the new editor (version 3) in a iframe the dialog window open only inside the iframe and not outside.
In version 2 the dialog (any dialog: image, link and more) was open all over the page and not inside the editor.

There is any solution for this problem?

Thanks,
Noam

Comment: I've found this http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8190
Seems to be the same problem, if it is then it is not possible to to this then?
Did you manage to fix this? thx

Comment: As Garry Yao wrote under the ticket - it isn't possible and wont be. Dialog has to live in the same document in which editor is defined.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any solution.

> CKEditor dialogs are not anymore popup windows thus are not able to
>   live outside the host window (the frame that contains the editor) just
>   like most of the other popular javascript UI libraries.

source: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8190